# Only remove the one child of the element, how to remove child with specific button?

Tags: javascript

In this, I want to remove the child with specific remove button. but when i run this code, it will remove only one activity that i have inserted in the input.

```
function addItemTodo(text){
    list = document.getElementById("todo");

    item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = text;

    trash = document.createElement('button');
    trash.classList.add('btn1');
    trash.addEventListener("click", removeActivity);

    icon_trash = document.createElement('i');
    icon_trash.classList.add('fas','fa-trash-alt','fa-2x');

    check = document.createElement('button');
    check.classList.add('btn2');

    icon_check = document.createElement('i');
    icon_check.classList.add('fas','fa-check','fa-2x');

    item.appendChild(trash);
    trash.appendChild(icon_trash);
    item.appendChild(check);
    check.appendChild(icon_check);
    list.appendChild(item);
}

//if user click on the button, remove the activity from the list of Activity

function removeActivity(){
    list.removeChild(item);
    console.log("item removed!");
}
```

Comment: i don't want to remove all child. i want to remove child with specific button clicked.

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: Console show me this error.                                                    Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at HTMLButtonElement.removeActivity (http://127.0.0.1:5500/script.js:43:10)

Comment: That usually occurs if the node doesn't exist in the dom tree. Can you confirm if that node is actually present in the dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change function removeActivity() to below code

```
function removeActivity(){
 var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
   listItems[i].onclick = function() {
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  }
   }
 }
```

[I have made a working demo on codepen have a look](https://codepen.io/shahidali/pen/NzrMXy?editors=1111)